# Powershell [Version] comparisons with different components used

Tags: powershell, version

I am attempting to do some version number comparisons, using the `[version]` type since it allows use of standard operators on version numbers. This works a treat so long as my version numbers being compared use the same components. So `[version]'1.2.3.4' -eq [version]'1.2.3.4'` returns true. However, if one operand doesn't use a component, this fails. So `[version]'1.2.3' -eq [version]'1.2.3.0'` returns false. This becomes a problem when you consider how sloppy many developers are with this data. For example, if you get a version number for the NotePadd ++ file, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` you will get all four components, but if you get the version number from the `DisplayVersion` property at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++` you get 7.5.9, no `Revision` component.
To address this, I would like to replace unused/empty component properties with `0`, so the conditional works consistently. However, when I tried

```
$version = [version]'1.2.3'
if (-not $version.Build) {$version.Build = 0}
if (-not $version.Revision) {$version.Revision = '0'}
Write-Host "$($version.Major)"
Write-Host "$($version.Minor)"
Write-Host "$($version.Build)"
Write-Host "$($version.Revision)"
```

I get `-1` as the `Revision` rather than the `0` I intended, and it doesn't matter if I use an int or a string as the assigned value.
Am I missing some technique for directly modifying component properties, or do I need to decompose the variable back into 4 strings, inserting `0` as needed, then recreate my `[version]` typed variable from the resulting string? `[version] | Get-Member | Format-Table` doesn't seem to expose any type specific properties or methods, just generic inherited stuff, which suggests I am stuck recreating my variable. Basically it seems like `[version]` is an immutable type.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0) doesn't mention any mechanism for changing properties, only getting current values, and it specifically says

> // The example displays the following output:  //       Relationship
> of > 1.1 to 1.1.0: Earlier  //       Relationship of 1.1.0.0 to 1.1.0:
> Later

Which makes some sense, and has me thinking this particular example with NotePad ++ really is just the developer screwing the pooch, and I SHOULD treat them as different and require that my data match what I expect to get back depending on which source of data I choose. Really disappointing to find an example of something this sloppy with a program I love. This is really Autodesk level sloppy. :(

But, I do still wonder if I am correct in thinking a `[version]` is immutable, and if I really do want to allow for this comparison I will need to rebuild my variable, rather than change it?

EDIT: Also, I did update my NotePad++ install to 8.1.4, and they are still showing all four components in the file version but only three in the registry. Which suggests this condition is not a simple mistake, but intended behavior. It SEEMS to me that bothy sources of data SHOULD match. But perhaps I am also missing some valid reason to have different data in these two locations?

Comment: Why should `1.2.3` be equal to `1.2.3.0`? If someone is talking about iOS 14, is he really talking about `14.0.0.0` or does he address any version `14.*` (e. g. `14.7.1`)?

Comment: @stackprotector I agree they SHOULD be considered different, and in iOS or macOS, where (I think) there is only one source of this info, the application file, that makes sense. But in Windows, where there are two sources of info, the OS does jack #%#$ nothing to ensure consistent data, and developers are sloppy because Microsoft is sloppy, sometimes they are "=". That said, 8.1.4 is still going to be > 7.5.9 or 7.5.9.0, so doing the test to see if I need to install the update still works. It just feels like the registry SHOULD reflect the same version number as the file.